Is it fine to make an API call inside a reinforcement learning program?
I have made a game simulation with rest of the API available, and I would like to create a reinforcement learning AI in Python using gym from OpenAI.
So, is it fine to make API calls inside the step function in my custom gym environment? Won't it be too slow? Or should I rebuild the simulation in Python?

Making API calls in a Gym environment's step function can slow down training. It's better to preprocess data, rebuild the simulation in Python for faster performance, and optimize API use by batching, caching, or using async programming to reduce delays.
